Причины активного использования дисков при выполнении запроса через rest-api
Такая проблема: есть большое представление, есть запрос из этого представления. Но при запуске в IDE:
SELECT * FROM my_view;

Запрос получает последнюю строку через минуты полторы. Когда через rest-api прошу сервер выполнить похожий запрос:
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM my_view) FETCH FIRST 1000 ROWS ONLY;

Обложку с ограничением накладывает сам сервер. Так вот второй запрос выполняется часов 10. Оба запроса выполнены под одним и тем же юзером. Залез в v$sql посмотреть что-нибудь, что бросится в глаза для этих двух уже выполненных запросов. Так вот, PHYSICAL_WRITE_BYTES (и _REQUESTS) как и PHYSICAL_READ_BYTES (и _REQUESTS) отличается раз в 40-50 (соответственно, у второго больше). Да и во время выполнения часто видел причину ожидания User I/O у второго запроса.
Вопрос: в чем может быть причина? Почему второй запрос активно полез на диски? Может ли быть такое, что второму не хватило кеша, при том, что он зашел под тем же юзером и как это можно проверить?

Напишите просто SELECT * FROM my_view FETCH FIRST 1000 ROWS ONLY. Подозреваю, что оракл сначала вычитывает таблицу и пытается ее куда нибуть в TEMP уложить, а затем уже выбирает из всего набора 1000 строк

Ну и для эксперимента проверьте план запроса для SELECT * FROM my_view order by 1 - скорее всего там тоже будет гигантское использование дисков. Если это так, то это TEMP

Ну к возможности завернуть запрос в обертку у меня доступа нет (продукт не наш, хотя доступ в базу есть и кастомные запросы можно пилить, которые через rest-api и запускаются), но через IDE я сейчас запустил в обёртке такой же - нет, справляется буквально секунд за 20.

С сортировкой тоже попробовал - точно такое же время выдает (быстро). Там выдача то строк на 4к, просто в процессе пол базы перелопатит.

В запросе нет ли WHERE и каких то сложных типов данных, на подобии коллекции? Я не встречал, что бы один и тот же запрос с одними и теми же параметрами отрабатывали разное время, тем более для вьюхи. У меня были случаи резкого ухудшения плана, но это было связано исключительно с тем, что разные условия в WHERE передавались. И не может ли ваша АПИ просто ДДОСить вас и вызывать эту вьюху 100500 раз? Очень не верится, что даже при фулскане 4к строк выбираются 10 часов

Нужно смотреть планы запроса, возможно через rest api не используется индекс.
Посмотрите ваши реальные планы выполнения через DBMS_XPLAN, например:
SELECT * FROM table (DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR('atfwcg8anrykp'));

sql_id найдите в представлении v$sql, например:
select * from v$sql where sql_text like 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM my_view)%';

Сравните планы выполнения. В медленном плане наверняка либо не используется индекс, либо есть сортировка.
Например, есть баг, в 12.1: При использовании fetch first ... rows only выполняется лишняя сортировка.

Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.

@aleksandrbarakin, спасибо за своевременное и безусловно очень ценное для всех замечание.

Это да, но если я увижу, что план выбран при запросе через апи плохой, то как мне заставить то его выбрать тот же, что у меня в консоли?
В общем, я забил на это дело. На проде эта проблема не вылезла, вот и ладушки =)
Похожая проблема была на постгресе, но там просто сбор статистики с лучшим качеством помог.
